# Can I check if an expression is positive using assumptions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I have the following notebook:

```
$Assumptions -> { {c1, c2, λ, μ} > 0, Element[{c1, c2, λ, μ}, Reals], μ > λ}

(* True -> {{c1, c2, λ, μ} > 0, (c1 | c2 | λ | μ) ∈ Reals, μ > λ} *)

f1 := c1 * (λ/(μ - λ)) + μ * c2

df1 = D[f1, μ]

(* c2 - (c1 λ)/(-λ + μ)^2 *)

Solve[df1 == 0, μ]

(* {{μ -> (-Sqrt[c1] Sqrt[λ] + Sqrt[c2] λ)/Sqrt[
   c2]}, {μ -> (Sqrt[c1] Sqrt[λ] + Sqrt[c2] λ)/Sqrt[c2]}}*)

 D[df1 , μ] 

(* (2 c1 λ)/(-λ + μ)^3 *)
```

The last line is getting the second order condition. Since all terms in the numerator are positive, the numerator is positive. Since $\mu > \lambda$ by assumption, then $(-\lambda + mu)^3$ is also positive for any $\mu$, $\lambda$ combination. Is it possible for *Mathematica* to use the stated assumptions to tell me that the second order condition is positive, given the set of assumptions?

Comment: To set global assumptions, use `$Assumptions = {{c1, c2, λ, μ} > 0, Element[{c1, c2, λ, μ}, Reals], μ > λ}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
df2 = D[df1,  μ]; 
$Assumptions = Flatten[{Thread[{c1, c2, λ, μ} > 0], Element[{c1, c2, λ, μ}, Reals], μ > λ}];

FullSimplify@Positive[df2]
(* True *)
FullSimplify@Sign[df2]
(* 1 *)
```

Or, you can use your assumptions directly as the rhs of the `Assumptions` option, or as the first argument of `Assuming`, without setting the value of the global variable `$Assumptions`:

```
FullSimplify[Positive[df2], Assumptions -> 
             Flatten[{Thread[{c1, c2, λ, μ} > 0], Element[{c1, c2, λ, μ}, Reals], μ > λ}]]
(* True *)
```

or

```
Assuming[Flatten[{Thread[{c1, c2, λ, μ} > 0], Element[{c1, c2, λ, μ}, Reals], μ > λ}],
        FullSimplify@Sign[df2]]
( * True *)
```

Similarly, for `Sign[df2]`.