# sign of expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, algebra

Can I show that the following expression is always positive,
$$b-a+a(\log a - \log b)$$
here $a>b$ and both $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers between 0 and 1. I have plotted this expression and I can see that it is positive but I want to show it analytically. Can anyone help ?

Comment: maybe it can be considered a mathematica problem

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58181/9490

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide by `b` (remember `b > 0`) and substitute `x = a/b` to get

```
1 - x + x Log[x] > 0
```

Then

```
Minimize[1 + x Log[x] - x, x]
(* {0, {x -> 1}} *)
```

Or analytically:

$$\frac{\delta}{\delta x}\left(1-x+x\log{x}\right)=-1+\log{x}+\frac{x}{x}=\log{x}$$

Which is $0$ when $x=1$.

$$f\left(x=1\right)=1-1+1\log{1}=0$$

But `x <= 1` is not allowed because `a > b`.  The expression is positive for `x > 1`.